# calculation based on footer row values in aspxgridview?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

i want to calculate footer value of particular column based on another columns footer row value. My grid data look like below.

```
             a   b   c     d
             1   1   1     5
             2   2   2     7
Grand total  3   3   3

In d column Grand tot based on the value of 
grand total of C column/Grand total of A column*100? 
How to calculate the grand total of D column for the above table
using DEVEXPRESS ASPXGridview control?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [custom summaries](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3762). Handle the [ASPxGridView.CustomSummaryCalculate](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_CustomSummaryCalculatetopic) event and implement your logic there. Follow the [Obtain Summary Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument5155) article to get values of other summaries.